# RNCookieManagerAndroid.get got 4 arguments, expected 3 -react native

Tags: react-native

here is code:

```
componentDidMount () {
    // Get cookies as a request header string
    CookieManager.get("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login", (err, res) => {

      // Outputs 'user_session=abcdefg; path=/;'
      fetch("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': res.csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: 'user',
          password: 'securepassword',
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
    });
  }
```

Above code shows error on emulator!!!

Screenshot of Android Emulator---

[image]

here installed

```
yarn add react-native-cookies
```

as well as other given instructions.
also imported in app.js file

```
import CookieManager from 'react-native-cookies';
```

Everything seems to be correct still showing this error..
Any suggestions are welcomed..
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module react-native-cookies implements **Promises** in it and it gives the response as a Promise object so the only thing you are doing wrong is the way you are handling the response of your **Cookiemanager.get** call.
Change your code as below and then you are good to go :)

```
componentDidMount () {
// Get cookies as a request header string
CookieManager.get("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login")
  .then((res) => {

  // Outputs 'user_session=abcdefg; path=/;'
  fetch("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': res.csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: 'user',
      password: 'securepassword',
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
  })

  }).catch((err) => {
      //handle your error here 
  })
}
```

This is what you are doing wrong. Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot i was stuck from 2 days, it not showing any error now and fetch method is working correctly, but that `CookieManager.get("http://10.42.0.1:8000/login")` is not giving any response on server means only fetch is hitting to the server with `username` and `password`. CSRFToken which i want to come with `CookieManager.get` is not coming what should i do for that...

Comment: Do you want to see the results of django server for clear information?

Comment: No idea about the django server. I think you need to add a different question for this. Your problem for above question is resolved :)